# Confusing the 'litt' value in 'elog2cbs' function of package "BTYDplus"

Tags: r

I am learning customer analysis with 'BTYDplus' package recently. Something confuse me about how 'litt' value calculate in the 'elog2cbs' function. Here is the code:

```
#install.packages('BTYDplus')
library(BTYDplus)
library(tidyverse)
data("groceryElog")
elog2cbs(groceryElog) %>% 
filter(cust == 10)
```

Results:

```
  cust x      t.x     litt      first    T.cal
   10  2  13.85714  2.782741  2006-01-03 103.7143
```

Notes the litt = 2.782741.
As help(elog2cbs) says:

> litt: Sum of logarithmic intertransaction timings during calibration period.

But according to this definition, I valid with 'tidyverse' package retrieve different value:

```
groceryElog %>% 
  filter(cust == 10) %>% 
  mutate(first = min(date),
         difftime = as.numeric(difftime(date, first, units = 'week')),
         ln_dif = log(difftime))
```

Results:

```
  cust       date      first  difftime    ln_dif
1   10 2006-01-03 2006-01-03  0.000000      -Inf
2   10 2006-01-12 2006-01-03  1.285714 0.2513144
3   10 2006-04-10 2006-01-03 13.857143 2.6288008
```

litt should be 0.2513144 + 2.6288008 = 2.880115 **NOT** 2.782741.

Then I checked the function code:

```
....
elog_dt[, `:=`(t, as.numeric(difftime(date, first, units = units))), 
    by = "cust"]
elog_dt[, `:=`(itt, c(0, diff(t))), by = "cust"]
cbs <- elog_dt[date <= T.cal, list(x = .N - 1, t.x = max(t), 
    litt = sum(log(itt[itt > 0])), sales = sum(sales)), by = "cust,first"]
....
```

With 'datatable' package, still

```
litt = sum(log(itt[itt >0])
```

the result is 2.88.

Anyone could enlighten me, many thanks.

Comment: Just throwing an idea: is there a place for numerical instability, e.g. very small numbers in `itt` ?

Comment: for cust 10 the difference between 2.88 and 2.78 is trivial, but not all the case. cust  26 for instance, litt = 2.505 in "elog2csb" but  5.376 by dpylr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out by myself. "itt" is the 'intertransaction' time peroid, which means it it should be

```
  groceryElog %>% 
  group_by(cust) %>% 
  mutate(first = min(date),
         difftime = as.numeric(difftime(date, first, units = 'week')),
         lag_time = c(0, diff(difftime)), #INTERTRANSACTION PEROID
         ln_dif = log(lag_time)) %>% 
  filter(cust == 10)
```